# Update-AzureVM to apply multiple chages

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine

Is it possible to use `Update-Azurevm cmdlet` to apply multiple changes. At the moment I am calling this to apply a single change and it's a little time consuming. Below is an example.

```
$VmGroups = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $Service

foreach (VmGroup in VmGroups) {

VmGroup | Set-AzureVMSize $VMSize | Update-AzureVM
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible. What you could do if you were using a VM in the Resource manager is run the foreach as a parallel operation. Eg Update-AzureRmVm